# Performing retries with ruby gRPC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grpc

I'm running a ruby app that uses gRPC to communicate with other services and am leveraging the [gruf gem](https://github.com/bigcommerce/gruf) for gRPC interactions.

I'm running into an issue where occasional resourcing issues cause gRPC calls to fail with `GRPC::Unavailable: 14:Connection reset by peer`.  I'm attempting to implement a retry mechanisim, but it does not look like the ruby gRPC implementation has one available.  I've looked at building a custom [ClientInterpreter](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/grpc/GRPC/ClientInterceptor) to perform a retry, but yielding multiple times in a ClientInterpreter results in a `GRPC::Core::CallError: attempting to re-run a call` error.  Is there a recommended way to do retries using gRPC in ruby?  Do I need to resort to writing in app code outside the gRPC/gruf ecosystem?